# phpmyadmin empty table and restart autocrement from 1

Tags: phpmyadmin

I had a question related to phpmyadmin. I have a table with the following criteria:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `client_name` varchar(120) NOT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I have inserted some test values to the above created table.
Now how I do empty the all the table values in the above table such that the next time I insert the values ,the autoincrement for id should start from 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind. I learned to do it the simple way in phpmyadmin. Just go to Operations and click on Empty(Truncate) Table.

Comment: Be warned, I just tried to 'empty' tables using this phpMyAdmin function and it trashed everything. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple things you could do:

As per [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) you could do:

```
DELETE FROM  `client_info` WHERE 1;
ALTER TABLE `client_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Another method might be to do:

```
DROP TABLE `client_info` ;
CREATE TABLE `client_info` (
 `id` INT( 11 ) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `client_name` VARCHAR( 120 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Although the first method should work, and seems easier. I added the PRIMARY KEY constraint in the create table statement, because MySQL gives me an error without it (I'm assuming id is the primary key).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

This should work.